# PDO nested array structure from multiple joins

Tags: php, pdo

I need to create an universal method/algorithm to create a hierarchical structure for this kind of data structure:

[image: Database structure]

The query, which obtains the result is something like this:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `Posts` 
JOIN 
   `Comments` AS `Comments` 
ON 
   `Posts`.`post_id` = `Categories`.`category_id` 
JOIN 
   `Likes` AS `Likes` 
ON 
   `Comments`.`comment_id` = `Likes`.`comment_id`
```

What i expect is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [post_id] => 1
        [post_message] => Test
        [Comments] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [comment_id] => 1
                [post_id] => 1
                [comment_message] => Foo
                [Likes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [like_id] => 1
                        [comment_id] => 1
                    )
                    [1] => Array
                    (
                        [like_id] => 2
                        [comment_id] => 1
                    )
                )
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [comment_id] => 2
                [post_id] => 1
                [comment_message] => Bar
                [Likes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [like_id] => 3
                        [comment_id] => 2
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**So my question is:**
Is there a simple way of doing this using PDO? I could manually iterate through the arrays, obtain the keys from information_schema, and create the sub-arrays, and yet more sub arrays ..., but that just feels like writing the join manually again.

I noticed, that there is a constant that can be used when calling PdoStatements fetchAll():

```
$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

which will group the data to some extent, but not the way i want to.

So is there a constant for this (or something similar like this), or do you know any clever callbacks to fetchAll, that will do this?